# Program that counts the number of ways a number can be decomposed into different summands

Tags: c#, math

I'm struggling with the problem of decomposing numbers into different multipliers. I've written some semi-working code using recursion. Unfortunately, it gives wrong answer when n=4.

Can someone tell me how to fix my method?

The program should output the number of different expansions consisting of increasing summands. For 6 for example 1+2+3, 2+4, 1+5

This is the code of my program:

```
using System;

namespace Stairs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count;
            Console.Write("Enter the number of cubes: ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (n < 3)
                count = 0;

            if (n >= 3 && n <= 8)
                count = CountStairs(n - 1, 1);
            else
                count = CountStairs(n, 1);

            Console.WriteLine("Number of different staircases: " + count);
        }

        static int CountStairs(int n, int min)
        {
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            int count = 0;

            for (int i = min; i <= n; i++)
            {
                count += CountStairs(n - i, i + 1);
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm used? Also: `if (n => 3 && n <= 8)` looks strange; shouldn't this be `else if`?

Comment: `if(n < 3) count = 0;` is superfluent. It will always be overwritten. Because if `n` is less than 3 it is also not greater than or equal to 3 which triggers `count = CountStairs(n,1);` (`else`-path of second `if`).

Comment: Haa also failed to understand. 2 should output 0 since the subset needs to be composed of increasing number. so 1=>0,  2=>0, 3=>1 [1,2], 4 => 1 [1,3], 5 => 2 [1,4]/[2,3], 6 => 3 [1,2,3]/[1,5]/[2,4] is that right?

Comment: That would be a convoluted, confusing hell of an assignment. Sometimes I wonder _what_ some teachers intend to teach.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work, but it also count such case as for example: 0+6 for number 6 or 0+5 for number 5. And if I'm not mistaken this is complete  [explanation](https://oeis.org/A000009)

```
public static int Stairs(int n, int m = 1)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (n < m)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (n == m)
        {
            return n % 2;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int k = m; k <= n / 2; ++k)
        {
            sum += (k % 2) * Stairs(n - k, k);
        }

        return sum + n % 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int Compute(int n, int min = 1)
    {
        int result = 0;
        //get each possibilities (i,n-i)
        for(int i = min; i < n; i++ )
        {
            //break once we go higher than half of the target
            if (i >= n-i)
            { 
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                result += 1;
            }
            // if the remaining is greater than twice the target, we run again
            if (n-i > 2*i)
            {
                result += Compute(n - i, i + 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

same result of Артем Павлов but without having the result for (0,n)
https://oeis.org/A000009

I tried with generating pairs to start
Exemple for n = 10:

- **i/n-i**
- 1/9
- 2/8
- 3/7
- 4/6

Then, if 'n-i' if more than '2*i':
I compute again but setting the 'min' with 'i+1'
So that for the pair 1/9, i will have:

- 2/7
- 3/6
- 4/5

The function is called again for 2/7:

- 3/4

Result for 10 is 9:

- 1 9
- --1 2 7
- ----1 2 3 4
- --1 3 6
- --1 4 5
- 2 8
- --2 3 5
- 3 7
- 4 6